# Unable to poll for mouse click event in SDL

Tags: c++, event-handling, sdl, user-input

I have the code

```
int userinput()
{
    while(hasquit == false)
    {
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                hasquit = true;
            }
            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                {
              hasquit = true;
                }
                if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                    {
                //do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is pretty much an event structure I copied from [these tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson08/index.php). I can get the SDL_QUIT and SDLK_ESCAPE events, but if I try to make

```
hasquit = true
```

with either of the mousebutton if statements, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the

```
if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
```

inside the

```
if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
```

block. It should be separate.

This should work:

```
int userinput()
{
    while(hasquit == false)
    {
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                hasquit = true;
            }
            if ( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                {
                    hasquit = true;
                }
            }
            if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's really frustrating. Oh well, it works now. Thank you!